# Does SQL Server have an equivalent to Oracle's PL/SQL Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008

I was wondering if SQL Server has an equivalent to Oracle PL/SQL Package? It is really nice to build your sprocs, functions, etc into a Package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if is a pure T-SQL equivalent, but you can Create all your procedures, functions into an .NET Assembly and the use it in SQL Server 2005 and higher.

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136(SQL.90).aspx)